# VS Code not allowing to select the correct kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I opened my vs code today to use a .ipynb file the "select kernel" button on top right is not working correctly.

It's showing just an old version of python (3.7.3) which is not the version I have installed.
I currently have python 3.10.6 on my OS, but I use Anaconda with Python 3.9.13

When I open a .py script VS Code shows the correct version. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1
Also, when I open jupyter notebook on Chrome it works normally

Can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter". Click Refresh in the upper right corner.

If it doesn't work, try the following way:

1.Use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and select **Reload Window** to reload the VS Code window.

2.Reinstall Python and Jupyter extensions.

3.Exit and restart VS Code.